# Is /sys/class/net/eth0/speed egress or ingress or combined speed of interface

Tags: linux, networking, centos, network-programming

I wanted to know what speed `/sys/class/net/eth0/speed` value in linux refers to? Is `/sys/class/net/eth0/speed` egress or ingress or combined speed of interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got my own answer in below link
https://serverfault.com/questions/1019024/is-the-total-bandwidth-for-a-typical-nic-switch-connection-full-duplex

Value in `/sys/class/net/eth0/speed` is for egress and ingress path individually. Means if it says 10Mbps then you will get 10Mbps for egress and 10Mbps for ingress